# WPF bind ComboBox selection to DataContext

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, combobox

In my XAML, `DataContext` is set to another class (what we call ViewModel, to separate the data from the interface control).
I have the following ComboBox in my XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LocationLists, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>
```

Therefore, LocationLists is a typed ObservableCollection in my DataContext.

Currently, I have the following Event:

```
Private Sub cmbList_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cmbList.SelectionChanged
        Dim ll As LocationList

        'Get the selected List
        ll = e.AddedItems(0)

        'Update the selected ListID in DataContext
        DataContext.ListID = ll.ID
End Sub
```

Everything works fine.

What I want: how to update `DataContext`'s `ListID` property to be always equal to the `ID` property of the `Location` object selected in `cmbList`, without any implementation in the Code Behind? Is it possible to do it only in XAML? Because basically it's just a binding issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LocationLists}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding ListID}" 
          SelectedValuePath="ID" />
```